# CSS: complex selector :parent and :not

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have this html code:

```
<div class='ui'>
    <h3 class='title'>
        <a href='#'>Link to Header</a>
    </h3>
</div>
<a href='#'>Another link</a>
```

I want to set a CSS style for all anchors a, but not the one that are into an h3 element that is parent of div.ui. I cannot add a class to the anchor a into h3 element.

I try this one:

```
a:not(:parent:parent.ui){color:#dedede;}
```

but this not work.
Any solution?

Comment: By the way: there is no `:parent` selector - you just made that up `:)` - http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/

Answer (score 10):

As Kobi noted in a comment, there is no such `:parent` selector.

Instead I suggest you style all `a` tags, then style `a` tags within `h3` tags within a different rule:

```
a { 
    color: #dedede;
}
.ui h3 a {
    color: another color;
}
```

Comment: Ok... then, my real problem is the jquery UI on an HTML5 layout. Infact, this layout have a style for simple anchor a, but the theme Darkness (as any other theme of jQuery UI) have complex stylesheet.